# Views in GridLayout are not equal

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-bitmap

I'm creating a GridLayout named channelView, which has bitmap icons as its views. But when the app runs on a device android 4.4.2 (only then) the first icon is smaller than the others. 
Here is my code:

```
File file = new File(CatchupActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),
                Util.getFileNameFromUrl(tch.icon));

        Bitmap icon;

        try{

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig =Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.outHeight = 150;
            options.outWidth = 150;
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);               

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            icon = Bitmap.createBitmap(120,120,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        channelIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.catchup_selector);

        GridLayout.LayoutParams pp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        pp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);


        channelIcon.setImageBitmap(icon);

        channelView.addView(channelIcon, pp);
```

And a screenshoot:
[image: screenshoot from app]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

`outWidth` and `outHeight` are output parameters, used by `inJustDecodeBounds`. Setting them yourself has no meaning.

In this case, it would appear that the `GridLayout` cell is the right size, as the rows and columns are all set up properly. Since the default width and height for children of a `GridLayout` are `wrap_content` and `wrap_content`, this would suggest that the image that you are loading into the `ImageView` is smaller than the others.

Comment: The images loaded are the same. Even when i swap first image with second, always the first is smaller

Comment: @MariaAgaci: I almost never use `GridLayout`, so I do not remember all the rules regarding the sizing of contents within cells. My guess is that you need more stuff in your `GridLayout.LayoutParams` to indicate that the `ImageView` should be stretched to fill the available cell space.

Comment: Do you have any idea why these is happening only on android 4.4.2 and on other version not?

Comment: @MariaAgaci: Off the top of my head, no.